# Problems while trying to get UTF-8 filenames using scandir

Tags: php, utf-8, scandir

I have files with filenames with Georgian letters, like

> დიადი განთიადი.flv.

Scandir can't read those filenames and it shows like `?????? ??.flv`.

I've tried the following:

```
$array = scandir($folder);
foreach ($array as $file) {
    //$file = iconv('WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8', $filename);
    //$file = iconv('ISO-8859-1',   'UTF-8', $filename);
    //$file = iconv('ISO-8859-15',  'UTF-8', $filename);
    pr($file);
}
```

but none of them worked, it still reads like `????`. I also tried setting header-content to utf-8 but with no luck. Is there any way I can read those filenames properly using PHP?

I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows (8.1)

Comment: Can you try running this on the Windows console? I am not familiar with Windows these days, but I expect their console is UTF-8 compliant by now. I don't know what `pr()` does, so can you swap this to `echo`?

Comment: pr is is just pretty echo.

Comment: Swap it anyway please, or show us the definition of it. How did you get on with trying this on the console?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, `scandir()` is able to cope with **URI percent-encoded** filenames, so, just off the top of my head:

```
$folder_encoded = rawurlencode($folder);
$array = scandir($folder_encoded);
```